# Get size of bit-field struct members

Tags: c, bit-fields

I have defined a struct like:

```
struct mystruct {
    uint32_t onebyte   :  8;
    uint32_t twobytes  : 16;
    uint32_t threebits :  3;
};
```

I know that C defines bit-fields to be at least as wide as specified, but the compiler may use more memory (e.g. 3*4 bytes in this case). However, the set width is a guaranteed minimum and if a value exceeds the according range, the application might still work correctly by chance.

To run some debug assertions, I want my code to check whether a value exceeds the allowed range before setting the member value:

```
assert(someval < (1 << sizeofbitfieldmemberinbits(((mystruct*)NULL)->threebits)));
```

For this specific case it might be a feasible solution to use a slightly different approach without any `sizeof()` call, but I am not sure if this is guaranteed to work:

```
assert(someveal <= ((mystruct){.threebits = -1}).threebits);
```

Anyway, is there a way to determine the guaranteed minimum size of a bit-field member of a C struct in bits (or at least in bytes)?

I am looking for an expression like `sizeofbitfieldmemberinbits()` that can be calculated by the compiler at build time (like `((mystruct){.threebits = -1}).threebits` can be evaluated to `0x7`).

Edit:
As John Bollinger pointed out, the memory allocated for a bit-field member can be larger than the specified number of bits, but the member can never hold a value larger than `(1 << #bits) - 1`. However, when I attempt to set a value that is out of bounds, it will be truncated implicitly (at runtime). With the assertion I want to check for cases where such truncation not just *might* occur, but when actually *does*.

Comment: You've put the question in somewhat strange terms with your concept of a *minimum* size.  Bitfields have *exactly* the size, in bits, that they are declared to have.  They are assigned storage inside an "addressible storage unit" that may be larger, but that doesn't mean that the bitfields themselves can have larger representations or can store values outside the range that their explicitly-sized representations afford.

Comment: See docs like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing, it should help!

Comment: Why can't you do `assert(x < 256); mystruct.onebyte = x;` ?

Comment: Note: A field type of `uint32_t` is not certainly supported: `_Bool, int, signed int, unsigned int.`are specified, others may not be.

Answer (score 2):

> I am looking for an expression like `sizeofbitfieldmemberinbits()` that
>   can be calculated by the compiler at build time

The Standard's term for what you are describing is "[constant expression](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6)":

> A constant expression can be evaluated during translation rather than
>   runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may
>   be.

(C2011, 6.6/2)

You go on to clarify the purpose for which you want to use such a constant expression:

> With the assertion I want to check for cases where such truncation not
>   just *might* occur, but when actually *does*.

Note, however, that

1. For that purpose, the size of the bitfield is secondary.  What you actually want is the maximum representable value.  For bitfields of signed types, maybe you want the minimum, too.
2. You don't actually need a constant expression for use in a regular assertion such as you demonstrate (as opposed to a static assertion).  The expression in a regular assertion is evaluated at runtime.
3. On the other hand, some expressions that do not satisfy the Standard's definition of a constant expression may still be computed at translation (compile) time by some implementations.

Points (2) and (3) are fortunate for you, because bitfields have second-class types that are not directly expressible.  There are no values of any bitfield type outside the context of a host structure object, and there is no type name with which the effective type of a bitfield can be expressed.  And *that* means there is no constant expression that evaluates to the number of bits or maximum value of a bitfield member, unless it incorporates prior knowledge of that member, because structs (including struct literals) are not among the operands that may appear in a suitable constant expression:

> An arithmetic constant expression shall have arithmetic type and shall
>   only have operands that are integer constants, floating constants,
>   enumeration constants, character constants, `sizeof` expressions whose
>   results are integer constants, and `_Alignof` expressions. Cast
>   operators in an arithmetic constant expression shall only convert
>   arithmetic types to arithmetic types, except as part of an operand to
>   a `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

([C2011 6.6/8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.6p8))

---

After all that, I think the question *really* boils down to this:

> I am not sure if this is guaranteed to work:
>
> ```
> assert(someveal <= ((mystruct){.threebits = -1}).threebits);
> ```

For unsigned bitfields such as your `mystruct.threebits`, it's guaranteed to work in C99 or later.  Earlier versions of C do not have compound literals or designated initializers, however, and some C implementations you might run into even today do not conform to C99.  On such an implementation, you might instead just define a (maybe `const`, maybe `static`) instance of your struct in which to record the limits ...

```
static const struct mystruct mystruct_limits = { -1, -1, -1 };
```

... and then compare to its members:

```
assert(someveal <= mystruct_limits.threebits);
```

Note here that struct member initializers are subject to the same conversions that apply in simple assignment, so as long as the members have unsigned types, the -1s as initializer values are well defined to have the wanted effect.

Note also that although the `const` is desirable for the purpose, it was not standardized until C99, either.  It was a pretty common extension before C99, though, and you are far less likely to run into a C compiler that rejects `const` than one that rejects compound literals.

Comment: The question is also about an optimal solution regarding code size. The more I can evaluate at translation time, the smaller the code. This also makes the use of const/static variables suboptimal. I am working on µC software, so code size really matters here.

Comment: @Thargon, as I said already, the assertion you proposed, involving a compound literal, is perfectly standard in C99 and later, and will have the effect you want.  You do not need the `static const` variable I described.  However, be aware that assertions are evaluated at *run* time, and therefore have corresponding code in your executable.  You might find that using a static structure object actually reduces your code size by allowing the assertions to be translated to simpler code.  But by all means, do test.

Comment: Also, you don't necessarily need to use an instance of the same structure whose members you are testing.  You can use any structure with a bitfield member having the appropriate type and width.  You could even consider defining a single such structure having members for all the bitfield types and widths you need to check.  The range of a bitfield is fully determined by its type and width.

Comment: I generally prefer temporal variables on the stack instead of global constants. But actually multiple initialization code of these temporal variables might quickly turn out to be heavier than a single global instance, indeed. Good advice, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to determine the guaranteed minimum size of a bit-field member of a C struct in bits
>
> I want to check for cases where such truncation not just might occur, but when actually does.

`assert()` is insufficient as its related code is not certainly present at runtime.

Check against the maximum value of the field.  Easy to do when the field is some *unsigned* type.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  struct mystruct {
    uint32_t onebyte :8;
    uint32_t twobytes :16;
    uint32_t threebits :3;
  };
  struct mystruct obj;

  for (int test = 0; test < 20; test++) {
    unsigned n = rand() % 10;

    // I want to check for cases where such truncation not just might occur,
    //  but when actually does.
    if (n > (struct mystruct) {.threebits = -1}.threebits) {
      printf("Truncation will occur, %u\n", n);
    }
    obj.threebits = n;
  }
  return obj.threebits;
}
```

Output

```
Truncation will occur, 9
Truncation will occur, 8
Truncation will occur, 9
Truncation will occur, 8
Truncation will occur, 9
```

Comment: I only  want to apply the `assert()` calls for debug builds, but get an optimized binary for non-debig builds. So your `if ()` solution is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @Thargon Then use `assert(n <= (struct mystruct) {.threebits = -1}.threebits);`

Comment: This is exactly what I proposed in my original question ;) Anyway, the question was not about assertion, but getting the size of bits in a bit-field. For my specific case there are other ways to solve my problem, but my curiosity is not satisfied, unfortunately.