# How to get a bit field size using a template?

Tags: c++11, bit-fields

I'm using a macro to compute the size of a bit-field. Would it be possible to use a template?

Code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*! 
@param reg a bit-fields structure
@param field name of one of the fields in 'reg'
*/
#define GET_FIELD_MAX(reg, field) ({ \
    decltype(reg) r; \
    r.field = ~0UL; \
    r.field; })

struct A {
    unsigned a : 3;
    unsigned b : 4;
};

int main()
{
  A x;
  printf("b size = %d", GET_FIELD_MAX(x, b));
}
```

Output:

```
b size = 15
```

Comment: Please make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is reg, field ? Why do you need to use a template ? Why don't you use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field ?

Comment: No, because there is no way to pass `field` into a template, as `&RegType::field` is illegal if `field` is a bitfield.

Comment: Somewhat related question → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064622/get-size-of-bit-field-struct-members -- nevertheless the C-style designated initializer is not really usable (in the standard) so your code can be adapted to use a immediately-invoked lambda.